# Use of regex on iso-2022-jp encoding with Python

Tags: encoding, unicode, python-3.x

I have some ISO-2022-JP encoded text.

Ex. : 
    まだ 正式 に 決まっ た わけ で は ない の で 。

According to the re library documentation, it can accept both ascii and unicode, so I tried to convert my text to unicode and to cut at the word level:

```
text.decode('iso-2022-jp')
print(text)
print(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text))
```

However, here is the kind of output I get:

```
まだ 正式 に 決まっ た わけ で は ない の で 。
['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', '5', '0', 'B', 'B', 'K', 'B', 'B7h', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'o', '1', 'B', 'B', 'G', 'B', 'B', 'O', 'B', 'B', 'J', 'B', 'B', 'N', 'B', 'B', 'G', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

What do I do wrong ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code work for me. (Python 3.3.0)

```
>>> text = "まだ 正式 に 決まっ た わけ で は ない の で 。"
>>> print(text)
まだ 正式 に 決まっ た わけ で は ない の で 。
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"[\w']+", text)
['まだ', '正式', 'に', '決まっ', 'た', 'わけ', 'で', 'は', 'ない', 'の', 'で']
```

BTW, you didn't assign the decoded string to text.

```
text = text.decode('iso-2022-jp')
```

---

**UPDATE**

I get following result, if I decode text as ascii (discarding non-ascii character).

```
>>> re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.encode('iso-2022-jp').decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
['B', 'B', 'B', '5', '0', 'B', 'B', 'K', 'B', 'B7h', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'o', '1', 'B', 'B', 'G', 'B', 'B', 'O', 'B', 'B', 'J', 'B', 'B', 'N', 'B', 'B', 'G', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

Seems like you're decode/encode incorrectly.

---

**UPDATE2**

If you read text from file, you don't need decode individual lines. Specify encoding in `open()` call.

```
import re
with open('results', 'r', encoding='iso-2022-jp') as f:
    for line in f:
        matches = re.findall(r"[\w']+", line)
        if matches:
            print(matches)
```

Comment: I load the text from my file very simply : 
`in_f = open("results", "r")`
`lines = in_f.readlines() `

Is it wrong?

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier: using `f.readlines()` you get the list of strings. You can use `f.read()` to get the multiline string instead. In Python 3, the `encoding=xxx` argument of the `open()` can be used to get the unicode content from the file with the xxx encoding -- see http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open. Anyway, you should always call the `f.close()` after reading the file (or use the `with` construct for opening).